# UIButton Image size

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I have 2 UIButtons.  I set the background images to 2 different pngs.  The pngs have different width.  I looks like this:

[image]

The button size is set to the images.size.width and height.

I would like these buttons to be the same size, but when I resize the buttons manually, the images gets distorted, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to resize my buttons without distorting the image?  Since it's a picture, I thought stretching doesn't make sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without distorting or ruining the integrity of the image the only real solution would be to add more padding to the right and left of the "delete" button.

Other options (which I personally would not reccomend) would include:

- split the "Reschedule" into two lines and shrink the alarm clock, so it would read:

  Re-

  Schedule
- Enlarge the trashcan icon manually (this will even them out a little more)
- Manually shrink the size of the reschedule icon (your legibility will suffer)

Regardless of the route you take I would resize or edit the original files in a program such as Photoshop or Fireworks to preserve the integrity of the UI elements. Be sure to scale proportionally in those programs to avoid more distortion and stretching.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, you are stretching the pictures size by resizing the buttons.  If I was you, I would look into manually resizing the images so that they are the same dimensions as your buttons.